# rust array initialization from range or collect

Tags: arrays, rust, iteration

Just started with rust and I'm trying some stuff with arrays and running into some difficulties. The first issue is initialization. I can create an "empty" array and iterate over elements to populate it, but how can I initialize from a range?:

```
let mut arr: [i32; 5] = [0; 5]; // this works
// let mut arr: [i32; 5] = 1..5 //this doesn't
```

The second problem is trying to initialize an array from a simple map over an array on i32. This doesn't work:

```
let mut arr2: [i32; 5] =  arr.iter().map(|&x| x + 1).collect();
```

Indeed even printing (without assigning) doesn't work:

```
println!("{:?}", arr.iter().map(|&x| x + 1).collect());
// the above fails with: "type annotations needed: cannot infer type for type arameter `B` declared on the associated function `collect`"
```

Any words of wisdom to offer?

Comment: You probably want a vec rather than an array if it is coming from a source with dynamic size.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703525/initialize-array-of-arrays-from-iterator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general problem here is that an array has a fixed size, known at compile-time, but the number of items in an iterator is not known at compile-time — even if it is an `ExactSizeIterator`, there's no const parameter for the size. Therefore, there are no *infallible* conversions from an iterator to an array.

However, there are *fallible* conversions available. The most straightforward commonly-useful one is [`impl<T, A, const N: usize> TryFrom<Vec<T, A>> for [T; N]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#impl-TryFrom%3CVec%3CT%2C%20A%3E%3E-for-%5BT%3B%20N%5D), which allows you to convert a `Vec<T>` to `[T; N]`, failing if the vector is of the wrong length.

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

let arr: [i32; 5] = (1..=5).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .try_into().expect("wrong size iterator");
```

This has the disadvantage of making a temporary heap allocation for the `Vec` and discarding it. If you do want the array to live on the heap, then you might want to use [`TryFrom<Box<[T], Global>> for Box<[T; N], Global>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-TryFrom%3CVec%3CT%2C%20Global%3E%3E-for-Box%3C%5BT%3B%20N%5D%2C%20Global%3E) instead, which allows you to get a boxed array from a boxed slice.

```rust
let arr: Box<[i32; 5]> = (1..=5)
    .collect::<Box<[i32]>>()
    .try_into().expect("wrong size iterator");
```

If you want the array to be stack allocated and to avoid temporary allocations, then you will have to work with `std::iter::from_fn()`, slightly awkwardly:

```rust
let mut iter = 1..=5;
let arr: [i32; 5] = std::array::from_fn(|_| iter.next().expect("too short"));
assert!(iter.next().is_none(), "too long");
```

(If you're confident in the length then there's no need to assert afterward, but an expect/unwrap inside is unavoidable.)

---

> The second problem is trying to initialize an array from a simple map over an array on i32. This doesn't work:
>
> ```rust
> let mut arr2: [i32; 5] =  arr.iter().map(|&x| x + 1).collect();
> ```

This doesn't work for the same reason as the first: you can't currently collect directly into an array. Any of the techniques I mentioned above will also work for this case.

Since this question and answer were originally written, arrays have now gained a method [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#method.map) which you can use to do this without going through an iterator:

```rust
let mut arr2: [i32; 5] = arr.map(|x| x + 1);
```

---

> Indeed even printing (without assigning) doesn't work:

This is actually a different problem than the others. `println!("{:?}", some_iterator.collect())` will always fail, because *you haven't specified what type to collect into.* `collect()` never assumes a collection type; it always has to be specified or inferred from context.

If you specify a type, then you can print the results of the iterator; whether the original input was an array is irrelevant.

```rust
println!("{:?}", arr.iter().map(|&x| x + 1).collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

Comment: copy_from_slice can make the explicit loop go away, but it's still fundamentally the same principle.

Answer (score 26):

#### As of Rust 1.63

Use [from_fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_fn.html):

```rust
let array: [usize; 5] = core::array::from_fn(|i| i + 1);
assert_eq!(array, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: Why is it incrementing the value of `i` each time? I would expect `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. I'm new to Rust.

Comment: @anilbey because the argument `i` here refers to the index not the value